# Using of plural nouns as adjectives

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between

**a three-week holiday**

**a three-weeks' holiday**

> I am so tired so I want to take **a three-week** / **a three-weeks** holiday.

Which one is more suitable to use or which is the correct one?

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/83260/two-year-program-or-two-years-program/83262#83262

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, here the `three-week` is an adjective for the `holiday`.

So you would say `a three-week holiday`,why I'm that sure is for when I came across a noun phrase which `six-people` was the adjective for `a six-people **bus**`, and I figure it out it was an adjective for the noun comes afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Nouns in compound adjectives don't take a plural form: a three-year old child, a five-minute walk or a five minutes' walk.

http://www.grammar.cl/english/compound-adjectives.htm